# IntersectionObserver или через скролл

Tags: javascript

Задача состоит в том, что необходимо за 10% от видимости(нижний край), подгрузить контент в блоки.
Есть возможность реализовать через IntersectionObserver, но что та мне подсказывает, что лучше сделать это через сколл.
Скрол как никак поддерживают все браузеры, IntersectionObserver это более свежий вариант.

Собственно вопрос в том, какой из вариантов будет менее затратным в плане нагрузки на процессор пользователя.

Вариант со скролом:

1. Через forEach, обходим все блоки и создаем массив.
2. Далее при изменении координат скрола каждый раз перебираем через
   цикл for
3. Подсчитываем расстояние нижнего края блока, скажем до нижней границы окна браузера.

Единственно, не совсем понимаю как подсчитать верно. Кто может скинуть на коленке написанный пример или формулу?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [IntersectionObserver - срабатывает сразу и не срабатывает при достижении за 10% до нижнего края](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1414094/intersectionobserver-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0-10)

Comment: Этот другой, про реализацию за счет  IntersectionObserver

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Lazy {
   
  #elements = []
  #offsetMultiplier = 0
  #offset = 0
  
  constructor(htmlElements, offsetMultiplier) {

    this.#elements = [...htmlElements].map(htmlElement => ({
      html: htmlElement,
      top: 0
    }))
    
    this.#offsetMultiplier = offsetMultiplier

  }
  
  
  enable() {
    
    addEventListener('resize', this.#handleResize)
    addEventListener('scroll', this.#handleScroll)
     
    this.#handleResize()
    this.#handleScroll()
    
  }
  
  
  disable() {
    
    removeEventListener('resize', this.#handleResize)
    removeEventListener('scroll', this.#handleScroll)
    
  }
  
  
  #handleScroll = () => {
     
    for(let i = this.#elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      
      const element = this.#elements[i]

      if(scrollY + this.offset > element.top) {

        this.#handleElementIntersection(element.html)
        this.#elements.splice(i, 1)

      }

    }
    
    
    if(!this.#elements.length) {
      
      this.disable()
      
    }
    
    
  }
  
  
  #handleResize = () => {
    
    this.offset = innerHeight + innerHeight * this.#offsetMultiplier
     
    this.#elements.forEach(element => {
      
      element.top = scrollY + element.html.getBoundingClientRect().top
      
    })
    
  }
  
  
  #handleElementIntersection(htmlElement) {
    
    htmlElement.classList.add('intersected')
    
  }
  
}


new Lazy(
  document.querySelectorAll('.lazy'),
  0.1
).enable()
```

```css
body {

  margin: 0;
  
}


.lazy {

  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  margin-bottom: 100vh;
  background-color: tomato;
  
}


.lazy.intersected {

  background-color: lightgreen;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="lazy"></div>
<div class="lazy"></div>
<div class="lazy"></div>
<div class="lazy"></div>
```